# How find last number of sequence numbers in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, qsqlquery

I want find last number of sequence in sql query for fill automatically suggestion field value. forexample my code field(column) is :1,2,3,4,10,20 so i want found 4 in my query

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking here. What do you mean by "field"? Field isn't a term used in SQL; you have columns, rows and values. Is your "field" (`1,2,3,4,10,20`) actually 6 rows in a column? 6 columns in a single row? A single comma delimited value? If you want the *last* number in the sequence, why `4` and not `20`?

Comment: I did not understand exactly what you mean, according to the example you gave, the last number in the sequence of numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 10 and 20 becomes 20, but why should 4 be a result?

Comment: I want find for complete autoNumber field automatically

Comment: what if your values are something like: (1),(2),(3),(11),(12),(13),(14),(20),(35), now what result do you expect? 3 or 14?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your table is called `table_name` and looks like this:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 10 |
| 20 |

Then this should work:

```
select min(previd) from 
(select id, lag(id) over(order by id) as previd
from table_name) t
where id - previd > 1;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f86dbadd7dc5d6191df989aa72167186)

Answer (score 0):

if the value of a column is for example '1,2,3,4,6,8,0' then you can use a function to get the last value from a sequence contained within a string.

```
create function dbo.FindLastNumberInSequence 
(
    @Delimited varchar(MAX),
    @Delimiter varchar(50) = ','
)
returns int as
begin
    declare @i int 
    declare @current int
    declare @previous int
    declare @sequenceFound bit = 0

    set @Delimited = @delimiter + @Delimited + @delimiter
    set @i = 1

    while   @i < LEN( @Delimited )
    begin
        set @current = SUBSTRING( @Delimited, @i+1, CHARINDEX( @Delimiter, @Delimited, @i+1 ) - @i-1 )

        if(@sequenceFound=1)
            if (@current != @previous + 1)
                break

        if (@current = @previous + 1)
            set @sequenceFound = 1

        set @previous = @current

        set @i = CHARINDEX( @Delimiter, @Delimited, @i+1 )
    end
    if(@sequenceFound=0)
        set @previous=-1
    return @previous
end

select dbo.FindLastNumberInSequence ('1,2,3,4,10,20', ',')  -- 4
select dbo.FindLastNumberInSequence ('9,8,1,2,3,4,10,20', ',') -- 4
select dbo.FindLastNumberInSequence ('9,8,1,13,4,10,20', ',')  -- -1 (no sequence found)
```

Comment: I misunderstood the question, it was not very clear. But the above answer does provide the last value in a sequence if that sequence is contained within a string. Which is how I read the question.